# How do i write INSTR in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

HOW do you write this in T-SQL ? I want to Just display the first 2 characters after the first open bracket.

```
(INSTR(main.cat, ':',1,1),0,' ', SUBSTR(main.cat,INSTR(main.cat, '(',1,1)+1,
```

INSTR(main.cat, '-',1,1)-(INSTR(main.cat, '(',1,1)+2)))  as "criteria",

```
From:      T: (A1 - 7)
TO:        A1
```

Also how do you change name field (which has both the surname and forename in one field)

```
from:   Smith, Paul
to:     Paul Smith


INSTR(emp.NAME, ',') +1, LENGTH(emp.NAME)-1)|| ' '||SUBSTR(emp.NAME, 1, INSTR(emp.NAME, ',')-1)
```

Comment: `CHARINDEX(',', emp.NAME)` Change `INSTR` to [CHARIDNEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

Comment: Asking two questions.

Answer (score 5):

You use `charindex()`.  Based on your description:

```
select substring(main.cat, charindex('(', main.cat) + 1, 2)
```

You might want to use a `case` to prevent errors if there are no parentheses:

```
select (case when main.cat like '%(__%'
             then substring(main.cat, charindex('(', main.cat) + 1, 2)
        end)
```

Comment: Please select this answer as accepted answer then @NiteCat